# Time complexity max min

Tags: performance, algorithm, time, divide-and-conquer

Simple linear search to find max min algo

```
maxmin(a,n,max,min){
max=min=a[1];
for i=2 to n do{
    if a[i]>max then max:=a[i];
    else if a[i]<min then min:=a[i];
}
}
```

1.Average case complexity of the above algo given that the first if conditions fails for n/2 elments
2.Average case complexity of the above algo if the first ccondition fails 1/2 times plz xplain

Comment: What is the programming language? It is 0-based, 1-based? What is the contents of `a`, `n`, `min`, `max`?

Comment: Homework question...?

Comment: its the algo for the problem actually we have to find the num of comparisons

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average case complexity for both cases is O(n). if k is the number of times the first if fails, then the number of comparisons is 2*n - 2 - k.

```
maxmin(a,n,max,min){
   max=min=a[1];
   for i=2 to n do{ // goes through the loop n-1 times
      if a[i]>max then max:=a[i]; // out of n-1 times succeeds k times and fails n-1-k times
      else if a[i]<min then min:=a[i]; // runs this n-1-k times
   }
}
```

n-1 + n-1-k -> 2*n - 2 - k

Comment: the num of comparisons in both cases is ?

Comment: you should not answer to homework questions without any afford of kriss singh...

Comment: thank you very much but could you plz explain how you got it